# Overload cast operator between two enums

Tags: c++, casting, enums

Is there a way to overload a cast operator to convert between two enums?

In my code I have

```
enum devStatus
{
    NOT_OPERATING,
    INITIALISING,
    DEGRADED,
    NORMAL
};

enum dataStatus
{
    UNAVAILABLE = 1,
    DEGRADED,
    NORMAL
}
```

where NOT_OPERATING and INITIALISING map to UNAVAILABLE; DEGRADED and NORMAL map straight across. These are fixed by external interfaces.

I am looking for a way to convert between `devStatus` and `dataStatus` and would like to be able to write something like:

```
devStatus devSts;
getDeviceStatus(&devSts);
dataStatus dataSts = (dataStatus)devSts;
```

I know that if these were classes, I could write `devStatus::operator dataStatus()` to do this. Is there a way of doing this for a enums?

I could just have a free function
`dataStatus devStatus2dataStatus(const devStatus& desSts)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++, conversion operators can only be declared within class, struct, and union declarations. They cannot be declared outside the type (like operator+, for example). Enum type declarations do not support instance members, so you will need to go with the conversion function. Doing so will also make the calling code clearer. The following example demonstrates this, using custom namespaces to scope the enumerations and conversion functions:

```
namespace TheirEnum {
   enum Type {
      Value1,
      Value2
   };
}
namespace MyEnum {
   enum Type {
      Value1,
      Value2
   };

   TheirEnum::Type ToTheirEnum (Type e) {
      switch (e) {
         case Value1: return TheirEnum::Value1;
         case Value2: return TheirEnum::Value2;
         default: throw std::invalid_argument("e");
      }
   }
}

// usage:
TheirEnum::Type e = MyEnum::ToTheirEnum(MyEnum::Value1);
```

Comment: What are the advantages/disadvantes of defining a class for each enum instead, and conversion operators?  On the downside more boilerplate code.  On the upside no conversion function floating around the outer namespace - though having said that the enums are already floating around there anyway.  Efficiency should be identical with compiler optimisation.

Comment: I agree that name scoping for C++ enums is not ideal, but it can easily be avoided by wrapping the enum declaration and the conversion function with a namespace, without having to go down the rabbit hole of creating a class for each enum. Going down that path brings up logical issues such as the is-a/has-a relationship and which operators should/must be provided for the type. I think that doing so is probably overkill for most enumerations.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example namespace declaration and sample usage.